# Visualization tools for 3C/Hi-C long-range interaction data?

Tags: software-recommendation, visualization

I have identified a genomic region (CpG island) that is enriched for a characteristic of interest in the vast majority of my samples.

After viewing it in the UCSC genome browser, I have confirmed that it does not overlap any annotated gene promoters, gene bodies, or retrotransposons, but am convinced that it is functionally interacting with something long range.

Is there a publicly available visualization tool where I can input my genomic region and get a list of topologically associated domains from 3C or other chromatin-chromatin interaction data?

Comment: What assembly is your genomic region of interest in?

Comment: The assembly I used was hg19/GRCh37

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would also recommend two very recent Hi-C visualization frameworks (with some public data available in both): [HiGlass](http://higlass.io/) and [JuiceBox](http://www.aidenlab.org/juicebox/).

Comment: HiGlass has the result of 7 different TAD callers available. Example using `hg38` can be found here: http://higlass.io/app/?config=IPCHmdOQR4CDY2sqj5VJHQ 

Another example using `hg19` is here: http://higlass.io/app/?config=OBa3x6FiQtSC5g8Mj6u0pQ

The TAD calls are from Forcato et al. 2017.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than a dozen or even hundreds of regions that you want to compare you could check a companion tool of HiGlass called **[HiPiler](http://hipiler.higlass.io)**. HiPiler lets you arrange, cluster, and pile up to thousands of genomic regions. Take a look at this [5min video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoLqje5OYKg) to see if the tool could help you to answer your questions.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of HiPiler.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the genome you want, you may be able to use the [chorogeneome navigator](http://chorogenome.ie-freiburg.mpg.de/), which is from some of my colleagues. This uses a number of public HiC datasets and allows you to view interactions.